# WCF: Global error handling in operation invoker for async calls

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, error-handling, asynchronous-wcf-call

I want a global error handling for my wcf service. Therefore I want to implement my own Operation Invoker. Every service operation has a response type inherited from a base response type. This base response type has a flag if the operation was successful a message and depending on the exception an error code (omitted in code snipet). 
The implementation for synchronous calls looks like the code further down, but how can I do the same for the asynchronous calls?

By the way: what do you think about that approach in general?

```
public class ErrorHandlingOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    private IOperationInvoker invoker;

    private ServiceDescription description;

    public ErrorHandlingLoggingOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker baseInvoker, ServiceDescription serviceDescription)
    {
        this.invoker = baseInvoker;
        this.description = serviceDescription;
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        try
        {
            result = this.invoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            BaseResponse response = (BaseResponse)Activator.CreateInstance(description.SyncMethod.ReturnType);
            response.error = true;
            response.errormessage = exception.message;
            return response;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: As nobody answers: Is this a good approach in general or should I search for another solution?